# How to synchronize a laptop with mobile phone so as to rack the login details of laptop?

Tags: laptop, security, bluetooth

I want to detect where my stolen laptop is.
If I synchronize the laptop with mobile phone using bluetooth so that when I login to my system it sends an alert message to my phone.   f
Now the issue is if the laptop is stolen and if the culprit already knows the login credentials of the laptop and the bluetooth range is not enough to work, how will i be able to get the alert message to the phone?

Answer (score 1):

So your laptop isn't stolen and you want to safeguard your laptop by having it send a message to your phone whenever it's logged in. First off, no criminal would be stupid enough to turn on the stolen laptop anywhere within bluetooth range of the house or the owner. The maximum range for class 1 bluetooth devices is 100 meters given optimal conditions (aka no walls, no storms, no high winds, no wifi networks nearby, no tv networks, no radio stations, nothing, just the bluetooth module on the laptop and the phone). So yeah, bluetooth is out of the question. However, you could set up the laptop to send an email whenever someone turn on and login to the computer.

http://www.howtogeek.com/123568/how-to-get-email-notifications-whenever-someone-logs-into-your-computer/

However, if said criminal is tech-savvy, they will most likely wipe the hard drive and reinstall the OS without every powering up and logging into an unprotected profile on your computer. In that case, you're dead out of luck.

Comment: While a clean install (formatting) might not be prevented, one can make it difficult; see http://help.preyproject.com/article/84-how-to-prevent-prey-from-being-removed Major problem is that, unlike stolen mobile phones, stolen laptops are often not connected to the internet. So getting notifications is difficult too.